# Two executables in one cabal file; stack build does not recognize them

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I'm trying to make 2 executables "project". All duplicates of this question did not help me - their answers don't fix my problem. I have .cabal file like this:

```
name:                int-tests
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            Integration Tests Suite
description:         Integration Tests Suite
license:             AllRightsReserved
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2018 Author name here
build-type:          Custom
extra-source-files:  README.md
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  hs-source-dirs:      common
  exposed-modules:     Common
  build-depends:       base
                     , text
                     , aeson
                     , network-uri
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  ghc-options:         -Wall -Werror

executable api-tests-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      api
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -Wall -Werror
  build-depends:       base
                     , hspec
                     , QuickCheck
  default-language:    Haskell2010

executable e2e-tests-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      e2e
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -Wall -Werror
  build-depends:       base
                     , hspec
                     , QuickCheck
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

and when I call `stack ide targets` I don't see these 2 targets. So, `stack build api-tests` and `stack build e2e-tests` don't work too.

How can I create 2 targets' project for stack? I tried also package.yaml but result is the same. Stack version is 1.9.1. I have folders tree like:

```
api/
...
e2e/
...
```

where are Main.hs files with content like:

```
module Main (main) where
main :: IO ()
main = print "Hello"
```

Also I tried option `-main-is Main` but without success.
Error looks like:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

Unknown package: api-tests
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `stack build` always builds all your targets. But if you want to be run just one executable, you'll need the full name including the `-exe`. So, `stack exec api-tests-exe` and `stack exec e2e-tests-exe`.

But what you really want to do is make these test targets: https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#test-suites

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in stack.yaml file, I had to add '.' folder to "packages:" section.